# C# Determine OS Version in .NET 6

Tags: c#, operating-system, .net-6.0

What is the correct way to determine the correct OS version in .NET 6?

I found many different solutions regarding this topic. All of them are quite out of date I think.

I want to get something like "Windows 10 Enterprise build 22000 (64 bit)"

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

gives "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22000.0"

```
RuntimeInformation.OSDescription
```

gives "Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000.0"

```
RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture.ToString()
```

gives "X64"

So far I'm using:

```
Console.WriteLine(RuntimeInformation.OSDescription + " | " + RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture.ToString())
```

This gives "Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000.0 | X64"

Is there a way to get something like "Windows 10 Enterprise | X64" in .NET 6?

In addition to that, I'm looking for a way to get the Windows install language and the current language.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the problem with code shown in the post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Windows Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405761/get-windows-edition)

Comment: Since .net6 can be used for cross-plattform applications, the answer of your mentioned question are not working. That's the reason I'm asking, because most of the anwers I found are like 10 years old.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify that. I.e. "I need Windows Edition name of the current OS running  .Net6 code on Linux, the suggested duplicate {link} works only for showing editions of Windows running on Windows" (or something like that).

Comment: Also note that if you care someone to see your answer to the comment you should @ - refer them like @KUMI... Also proper comments do not need replies but rather edits to the post (as comments are for asking clarification for questions/answers rather than starting discussion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```cs
RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture.ToString();
```

returns the architecture that the OS was compiled, that is, in this case it was x86-64 (string-shaped)

The functions:

```cs
Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
RuntimeInformation.OSDescription
```

returns windows version

With this and with this link here:
([Get OS Version / Friendly Name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp)) we can get to this code:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Management;

static int GetARCHFriendlyBits(Architecture architecture)
{
    return architecture switch
    {
        Architecture.X64 => 64,
        Architecture.X86 => 32,
        Architecture.Arm64 => 64,
        Architecture.Arm => 32,
        Architecture.Wasm => -1,
        Architecture.S390x => -1,
        _ => -1,
    };
}

static string GetOSFriendlyName1()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        ManagementObject os = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
        if (os["Caption"].ToString() is string osResult)
            result = osResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return $"{RuntimeInformation.OSDescription} ({RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture})";
    }

    if (result == string.Empty)
        return $"{RuntimeInformation.OSDescription} ({RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture})";
    else
        return $"{result} build {Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build} ({GetARCHFriendlyBits(RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture)} bits)";
}

static string GetOSFriendlyName2()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        ManagementObject os = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().First();
        if (os["Caption"].ToString() is string osResult)
            result = osResult;
    }
    else
    {
        return $"{RuntimeInformation.OSDescription} ({RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture})";
    }

    if (result == string.Empty)
        return $"{RuntimeInformation.OSDescription} ({RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture})";
    else
        return $"{result} | {RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture}";
}

Console.WriteLine(GetOSFriendlyName1());
Console.WriteLine(GetOSFriendlyName2());
```

which in my case writes this line here on the console:

```
Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language build 22621 (64 bits)
Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language | X64
```

To use `System.Management`, I had to install microsoft NuGet `System.Management`