# How to detect the user OS

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am writing a application in which I need to create log for this I have to detect the OS that user using.Basically I am doing this from check OS version but the issue is both Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 has the same version ie 6.0.So there is any other method to find the OS of user.

```
if (OSInfo.dwMajorVersion == 5 && OSInfo.dwMinorVersion == 1)
{
    s.AppendLine("OS Version              :" + " " + "Windows XP " + OSInfo.szCSDVersion + " " + "(Build Number : " + OSInfo.dwBuildNumber + ")");
}
else if (OSInfo.dwMajorVersion == 6 && OSInfo.dwMinorVersion == 0 && OSInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize == 152 ) //&& OSInfo.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
{
    s.AppendLine("OS Version              :" + " " + "Windows VISTA/Windows Server 2008 " + OSInfo.szCSDVersion + " " + "(Build Number : " + OSInfo.dwBuildNumber + ")");
}
else if (OSInfo.dwMajorVersion == 6 && OSInfo.dwMinorVersion == 1)
{
    s.AppendLine("OS Version              :" + " " + "Windows7 " + OSInfo.szCSDVersion + " " + "(Build Number :" + OSInfo.dwBuildNumber + ")");
}
else if (OSInfo.dwMajorVersion == 5 && OSInfo.dwMinorVersion == 2)
{
    s.AppendLine("OS Version              :" + " " + "Windows Server 2003 " + OSInfo.szCSDVersion + " " + "(Build Number :" + OSInfo.dwBuildNumber + ")");
}
```

Comment: Please don't do it that way. Also, read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/13/72476.aspx - if you are using this for log purposes, why does it have to be pretty? Isn't it enough to dump out the contents of `OSVERSIONEX` in text form?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `Environment.OSVersion`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You could read this stackoverflow post [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-7-in-net) or this article could help you http://andrewensley.com/2009/06/c-detect-windows-os-part-1/

Best regards