# C#, how make a if loop statement for windows version like windows 8 or windows 10?

Tags: c#, automation

i have write automation code for product which i'm currently working on and some functionality is various according to windows version. to tacks those functions i planned to have if loop for windows local and if you have better idea then this means pls update it

Note: i'm beginner Automation testing

Comment: Please share some of your code and rephrase your question as it is really hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Windows version in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //Get Operating system information.
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        //Get version information about the os.
        Version vs = os.Version;

        if (vs.Major == 10 && vs.Minor == 0)  // Test flow for WINDOWS 10 environment 
        {
        }
        else if (vs.Major == 6 && vs.Minor == 3)  // Test flow for WINDOWS 8.1 environment 
        {
        }
        else                             // Test flow for WINDOWS 7 and 8 environment  
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the system/environment to get the value for the windows build and version .

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.1+ you can no longer use the OSVersion (it will always show Windows Version 8). Instead you should include an [App Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) and write different scripts based on the targeted environment.

Comment: hi guys thanks a lot for all of your comments, but i have figured out something else and it working fine for me
which is

Answer (score 0):

You can read from regsirty through code and do specific action what you intended.

Say for ex:

Registry key you can find here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion and then look for "ProductName"

You can open registry information by giving regedit.exe in run (windows+r)

```
 var reg = 
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion");

 string productName = (string)reg.GetValue("ProductName");

 if(productName.StartsWith("Windows 10"))
 {
 }
else
 {
 }
```