# .NET Standard 2.0 get current Operating System

Tags: c#, operating-system, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

In .NET Standard 2.0, do I have any ways of determining the operating system and architecture on which my library is running ?

I need to know the OS and architecture to determine which version of nodejs to extract and run at run-time.

Edit about comments :
I already found the two methods that you offer but, according to the documentation [OperatingSystem.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.80).aspx) supports the following .net version (standard 2.0 isn't included it seems)

[image: OperatingSystem.version]
[image: Environement.OSVersion]

edit 2 - not a duplicate : As per my first edit above, my question targets .NET Standard 2.0, not .NET Framework or .NET Core.
.NET Standard 2.0 is crossplateform byt [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/304283) only lists windows version which is a very good way to know that this cannot match my needs.

Comment: See [System.Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

Comment: It looks like the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819974/6838730) on the "possible duplicate" answer might solve my problem. I'll try it in more details and let you know.

Comment: This would also mean that the documentation is not up-to-date regarding the APIs available in .NET Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research and a better understanding of the `Environment.OSVersion` property, I now know that this question is, in fact, a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net).

What led me to believing it was not is that, since the documentation doesn't show that these properties and methods are available in .NET Standard 2.0 i assume they were not and didn't take the time to try it.

So I simply copy/pasted the code from the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819974/6838730) and saw that no error was thrown ...

Comment: I do not know how to to tag my own question as duplicate after I contested a duplicate vote ...

Answer (score 4):

`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)`
`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)`
`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)`

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding some explanation of why you recommend `RuntimeInformation` as a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this after looking around abit:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx

BLANKhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version(v=vs.110).aspx

edit:
Found another resource that I think is what you're looking for:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-determine-operating-c90d351b

Comment: this one might help ! i'll try it when i have a few minutes. Thanks for your time, i'll let you know :-)

Answer (score 0):

[RuntimeInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=net-6.0) has the data for the architecture and you can test, if you are on Windows or another OS.