# c# trouble displaying unicode card suits between different versions of Windows

Tags: c#, unicode, console-application

Using c# .net 4.7.1, I'm trying to make a console app Blackjack game and I'm having trouble displaying the card suits to the console output with different versions of Windows. For Windows 7, this is the `Main` method that displays the suits correctly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] Suits = new string[] { "♠", "♣", "♥", "♦" };
    Methods.Print(Suits[0] + " " + Suits[1] + " " + Suits[2] + " " + Suits[3]);
    Console.ReadLine();
    ....
}
```

the suits display as I want them, like this:

[image]

But if I run my program with this `Main` method in it on my Windows 10 machine they display like this:

[image]

I've found that if I include this line in my `Main` method on my Windows 10 machine then the suits display as I want them to:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

But then that makes it so the suits don't display correctly on my Windows 7 machine. Can anyone help me out with how I can have these card suits display properly regardless of what Windows OS the program is run on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: cant hold the urge to put [this](https://www.xkcd.com/1726/). i could not think something else but to [do some probing to check the windows version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net).. if its Windows 10, you can configure the console to use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`, otherwise left it as it is..

Comment: @BagusTesa , I thought about that but the one thing that could still be a problem is I don't know what other versions of Windows this app might be run on. I could account for Windows 7 and Windows 10, but what about other versions of Windows? Also, in looking at that prospect, I saw someone post that the Service Pack installed has an affect on how it's displayed too. I only have access to a Windows 7 machine and a Windows 10 machine so I can't test it out on other versions of Windows let alone different Service Packs. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tymtam for the insight on the issue I'm having. I looked into the possibility of changing the console font as a solution. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c276b9ae-dc4c-484a-9a59-1ee66cf0f1cc/c-changing-console-font-programmatically?forum=csharpgeneral) article that shows how to programmatically change the console font to `Lucida Console` which is a true type font. Here's my formatted code from that link:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BlackJack
{
    class BlackJack
    {       
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr consoleOutput, bool maximumWindow, ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX consoleCurrentFontEx);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int dwType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetConsoleFont(IntPtr hOut, uint dwFontNum);

        private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        private const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 4;
        private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
        private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
        {
            internal uint cbSize;
            internal uint nFont;
            internal COORD dwFontSize;
            internal int FontFamily;
            internal int FontWeight;
            internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COORD
        {
            internal short X;
            internal short Y;

            internal COORD(short x, short y)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
            }
        }

        public static void SetConsoleFont(string fontName = "Lucida Console")
        {
            unsafe
            {
                IntPtr hnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
                if (hnd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX info = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                    info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);

                    // Set console font to Lucida Console.
                    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX newInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                    newInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(newInfo);
                    newInfo.FontFamily = TMPF_TRUETYPE;
                    IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(newInfo.FaceName);
                    Marshal.Copy(fontName.ToCharArray(), 0, ptr, fontName.Length);

                    // Get some settings from current font.
                    newInfo.dwFontSize = new COORD(info.dwFontSize.X, info.dwFontSize.Y);
                    newInfo.FontWeight = info.FontWeight;
                    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref newInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            SetConsoleFont();
            ....
        }
```

Two things to note

1. I had to add this using statement for it to work:

   `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`
2. I had to check the `Allow unsafe code` checkbox located in the `Project>Properties>Build` screen as shown below:

[image]

After making these changes the program runs on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 and it displays the card suits as I want them to. Like I said before, I don't have access to machines that have other versions of Windows on them, so I can only say that this runs on Windows 7 and Windows 10 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work reliably in the console then here is my solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("D, C, H, S");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here are 2 other options:

- Check windows versions and test all scenarios using `♠`, `♣`, `♥`, `♦` and `Encoding.UTF8`;
- Gui application.

## Windows 7

The problem with Windows7 console and

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("♠, ♣, ♥, ♦");
Console.ReadLine();
```

is most likely the font in console app.

From [Console.OutputEncoding Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_OutputEncoding):

> Note that successfully displaying Unicode characters to the console requires the following:
>
> The console must use a TrueType font, such as Lucida Console or Consolas, to display characters.

You can change the font in the `Console` app's properties:

[image]