# How do I determine sub versions of Windows 7 programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to determine whether a machine is running Windows 7 Pro, or Windows 7 Embedded. Environment.OSVersion returns the same version number on both systems, as does the Windows Management Interface. I'm looking at the Registry for some form of identifier, but I'm wondering if there is a solution I haven't considered yet.

Comment: You can use WMI with [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-operatingsystem) (seeOSProductSuite, SuiteMask and/or ProductSKU) or call [`GetVersionEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexw) as long as you don't need to worry about Windows 8.1 or above.

Comment: Also see [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2819934/1364007).

Answer (score -1):

Run the above code to get the OS details:

```
  using System;

    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var os = Environment.OSVersion;
            Console.WriteLine("Current OS Information:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Platform: {0:G}", os.Platform);
            Console.WriteLine("Version String: {0}", os.VersionString);
            Console.WriteLine("Version Information:");
            Console.WriteLine("   Major: {0}", os.Version.Major);
            Console.WriteLine("   Minor: {0}", os.Version.Minor);
            Console.WriteLine("Service Pack: '{0}'", os.ServicePack);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for what I need. Both Windows 7 Pro and Windows 7 Embedded return the same value: Win32NT, NT 6.1.7601 SP 1.

Comment: Try this By changing the language of your machine.
https://www.askvg.com/fix-something-happened-error-message-in-windows-10-upgrade/