# Detecting OS Edition

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

I would like to know if there is a possibility other than from registry to find the OS edition. I don't mean version like Win7, 10, etc., but Home, Professional, Enterprise, etc.

Even when I find it in the registry there is "Enterprise" on Pro version of Windows 10.

I just need to know how to achieve that on Windows 10.

I found this article:

[Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

But I dont see an option for `Environment.OSVersion` to return edition of windows.

Is it maybe possible through WMI?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes,thank you, didnt showed up in google for some reason when i googled how to get windows edition in C#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple way to do it using WMI

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"))
{
    var obj = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().FirstOrDefault();
    string version = obj["Caption"].ToString();                 //Microsoft Windows 10 Home
    string architecture = obj["OSArchitecture"].ToString();     //64-bit
}
```