# How to detect the Windows version in C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system

I'm writing C# code (.NET 6) in MacOS to behave different in 2 Windows Platforms. One is Windows 7 and the other is Windows Server 2008 R2. I learned from MSDN that these 2 OS platforms share the same major version and minor version!

The version map is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version. We could see that the major is 6 and the minor is 1. I can't specify the OS platform

Could anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: set environment variable and in Program.cs to read the variable

Comment: Thx! But could you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe this will help a bit: 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code sample will help you

```
static class WindowsOperatingSystemHelper
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.SafeDirectories)]
        public static extern bool GetProductInfo(
           int dwOSMajorVersion,
           int dwOSMinorVersion,
           int dwSpMajorVersion,
           int dwSpMinorVersion,
           out int pdwReturnedProductType);
    
        public enum OperatingSystemSKU
        {
            UNDEFINED = 0,
            ULTIMATE = 1,
            HOME_BASIC = 2,
            HOME_PREMIUM = 3,
            ENTERPRISE = 4,
            HOME_BASIC_N = 5,
            BUSINESS = 6,
            STANDARD_SERVER = 7,
            DATACENTER_SERVER = 8,
            SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER = 9,
            ENTERPRISE_SERVER = 10,
            STARTER = 11,
            DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE = 12,
            STANDARD_SERVER_CORE = 13,
            ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE = 14,
            ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64 = 15,
            BUSINESS_N = 16,
            WEB_SERVER = 17,
            CLUSTER_SERVER = 18,
            HOME_SERVER = 19,
            STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER = 20,
            STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER = 21,
            STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER = 22,
            STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER = 23,
            SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS = 24,
            SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM = 25,
            HOME_PREMIUM_N = 26,
            ENTERPRISE_N = 27,
            ULTIMATE_N = 28,
            WEB_SERVER_CORE = 29,
            MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_MANAGEMENT = 30,
            MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_SECURITY = 31,
            MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_MESSAGING = 32,
            SERVER_FOUNDATION = 33,
            HOME_PREMIUM_SERVER = 34,
            SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS_V = 35,
            STANDARD_SERVER_V = 36,
            DATACENTER_SERVER_V = 37,
            ENTERPRISE_SERVER_V = 38,
            DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE_V = 39,
            STANDARD_SERVER_CORE_V = 40,
            ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE_V = 41,
            HYPERV = 42,
            STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER_CORE = 43,
            STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE = 44,
            STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER_CORE = 45,
            STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE = 46,
            STARTER_N = 47,
            PROFESSIONAL = 48,
            PROFESSIONAL_N = 49,
            SB_SOLUTION_SERVER = 50,
            SERVER_FOR_SB_SOLUTIONS = 51,
            STANDARD_SERVER_SOLUTIONS = 52,
            STANDARD_SERVER_SOLUTIONS_CORE = 53,
            SB_SOLUTION_SERVER_EM = 54,
            SERVER_FOR_SB_SOLUTIONS_EM = 55,
            SOLUTION_EMBEDDEDSERVER = 56,
            SOLUTION_EMBEDDEDSERVER_CORE = 57,
            PROFESSIONAL_EMBEDDED = 58,
            ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_MGMT = 59,
            ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_ADDL = 60,
            ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_MGMTSVC = 61,
            ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_ADDLSVC = 62,
            SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM_CORE = 63,
            CLUSTER_SERVER_V = 64,
            EMBEDDED = 65,
            STARTER_E = 66,
            HOME_BASIC_E = 67,
            HOME_PREMIUM_E = 68,
            PROFESSIONAL_E = 69,
            ENTERPRISE_E = 70,
            ULTIMATE_E = 71,
            ENTERPRISE_EVALUATION = 72,
            MULTIPOINT_STANDARD_SERVER = 76,
            MULTIPOINT_PREMIUM_SERVER = 77,
            STANDARD_EVALUATION_SERVER = 79,
            DATACENTER_EVALUATION_SERVER = 80,
            ENTERPRISE_N_EVALUATION = 84,
            EMBEDDED_AUTOMOTIVE = 85,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY_A = 86,
            THINPC = 87,
            EMBEDDED_A = 88,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY = 89,
            EMBEDDED_E = 90,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY_E = 91,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY_A_E = 92,
            STORAGE_WORKGROUP_EVALUATION_SERVE = 95,
            STORAGE_STANDARD_EVALUATION_SERVER = 96,
            CORE_ARM = 97,
            CORE_N = 98,
            CORE_COUNTRYSPECIFIC = 99,
            CORE_SINGLELANGUAGE = 100,
            CORE = 101,
            PROFESSIONAL_WMC = 103,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY_EVAL = 105,
            EMBEDDED_INDUSTRY_E_EVAL = 106,
            EMBEDDED_EVAL = 107,
            EMBEDDED_E_EVAL = 108,
            NANO_SERVER = 109,
            CLOUD_STORAGE_SERVER = 110,
            CORE_CONNECTED = 111,
            PROFESSIONAL_STUDENT = 112,
            CORE_CONNECTED_N = 113,
            PROFESSIONAL_STUDENT_N = 114,
            CORE_CONNECTED_SINGLELANGUAGE = 115,
            CORE_CONNECTED_COUNTRYSPECIFIC = 116,
            CONNECTED_CAR = 117,
            INDUSTRY_HANDHELD = 118,
            PPI_PRO = 119,
            ARM64_SERVER = 120,
            EDUCATION = 121,
            EDUCATION_N = 122,
            IOTUAP = 123,
            CLOUD_HOST_INFRASTRUCTURE_SERVER = 124,
            ENTERPRISE_S = 125,
            ENTERPRISE_S_N = 126,
            PROFESSIONAL_S = 127,
            PROFESSIONAL_S_N = 128,
            ENTERPRISE_S_EVALUATION = 129,
            ENTERPRISE_S_N_EVALUATION = 130,
            HOLOGRAPHIC = 135,
            PRO_SINGLE_LANGUAGE = 138,
            PRO_CHINA = 139,
            ENTERPRISE_SUBSCRIPTION = 140,
            ENTERPRISE_SUBSCRIPTION_N = 141,
            DATACENTER_NANO_SERVER = 143,
            STANDARD_NANO_SERVER = 144,
            DATACENTER_A_SERVER_CORE = 145,
            STANDARD_A_SERVER_CORE = 146,
            DATACENTER_WS_SERVER_CORE = 147,
            STANDARD_WS_SERVER_CORE = 148,
            UTILITY_VM = 149,
            DATACENTER_EVALUATION_SERVER_CORE = 159,
            STANDARD_EVALUATION_SERVER_CORE = 160,
            PRO_WORKSTATION = 161,
            PRO_WORKSTATION_N = 162,
            PRO_FOR_EDUCATION = 164,
            PRO_FOR_EDUCATION_N = 165,
            AZURE_SERVER_CORE = 168,
            AZURE_NANO_SERVER = 169,
            ENTERPRISEG = 171,
            ENTERPRISEGN = 172,
            SERVERRDSH = 175,
            CLOUD = 178,
            CLOUDN = 179,
            HUBOS = 180,
            ONECOREUPDATEOS = 182,
            CLOUDE = 183,
            ANDROMEDA = 184,
            IOTOS = 185,
            CLOUDEN = 186,
        }
    
    
        public static bool TryGetOperatingSystem(this Version version, out OperatingSystemSKU sku)
        {
            sku = OperatingSystemSKU.UNDEFINED;
            if (GetProductInfo(version.Major, version.Minor, 0, 0, out int productType))
            {
                sku = (OperatingSystemSKU)productType;
            }
            return sku != OperatingSystemSKU.UNDEFINED;
        }
        public static bool IsWindowsServer()
        {
            if (TryGetOperatingSystem(Environment.OSVersion.Version, out var osSKU))
            {
                return osSKU.ToString().Contains("SERVER") || osSKU.ToString().Contains("DATA_CENTER") || osSKU == OperatingSystemSKU.CLUSTER_SERVER;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```